# Objective-C array breaks when I put the tintColor in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Today I encountered a problem: `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. They both break when I put the application `tintColor` as an element in them.

```
UIColor *temp = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].tintColor;
self.usedSliderColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: temp,
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:160.0f/255.0f blue:16.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0],
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], nil];

 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.usedSliderColors count]]);
 self.notificationLabel.backgroundColor = self.usedSliderColors[1];
```

In the scenario above I try using `self.usedSliderColors[1]`, or any other object from the array, the application breaks, with the error message that the array is empty. But if I put a `NSLog` before the use statement it gives me size of 3.

On the other hand if I change the tint to another UIColor it works:

```
self.usedSliderColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIColor blueColor],
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:160.0f/255.0f blue:16.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0],
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], nil];

 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.usedSliderColors count]]);
 self.notificationLabel.backgroundColor = self.usedSliderColors[1];
```

So my question is if someone knows a way around that, or if I'm making some stupid mistake?

Comment: if the actual `temp` is `nil` that pretty much marks the last item in your array – if that is the first item, that means the rest of the items are ignored; you can resolve the issue by e.g. `... = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: temp?:[UIColor clearColor], ...`, or something like that for being sure the array has all 3 items you expect later.

Comment: This is the best reason to use the array literal syntax.  You would have gotten a nice clear runtime error, telling you that you attempted to insert `nil` into an array.

Comment: @Avi, he has got an exception, but not for inserting a `nil` into the array; no such thing happens here.

Comment: @holex, I know he's not inserting a nil into the array.  However, *if* he used the literal syntax, he'd have found his bug as soon as the runtime error threw the exception.  He avoided a crash at the expense of allowing a logic bug that stumped him.  Don't fight the compiler, even inadvertently!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to resolve the scenario when the `temp` is `nil`, because if that happens, then this line:

```
self.usedSliderColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: temp, [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:160.0f/255.0f blue:16.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], nil];
```

is identical to this:

```
self.usedSliderColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

which is an array with 0 items, therefore the index `[1]` is outside of the bound.

---

if you want to be sure all 3 items  will be in your array, you can do something like that (if logically that fits in your workflow, of course):

```
self.usedSliderColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: temp?:[UIColor clearColor], [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:160.0f/255.0f blue:16.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], nil];
```

because that is syntactically totally perfect for having the 3 colours in your array, and now the index `[1]` exists – which you want to refer later.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Your `temp` color may be nil. Try to `NSLog` it before adding it in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.usedSliderColors.count);` before you access the 2nd element of the array, you will see that the count is 0.

What is happening here is that the `tintColor` is `nil`, which means that no elements are getting added to your array.